# Spinner displaying wrong images

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner that acts as a drop-down menu.  When I press on the spinner, it should display two images.  It displays two images however it is not the right ones. It is displaying the two buttons above the drop-down menu.

I have tried moving around the position of the drop-down menu to see if placement is the issue. I have tried moving around the initialization code.  I have tried putting the spinner in the onClick() method.

```
// Drop down menu
int[] sights = {R.drawable.reticle,R.drawable.reticle2};    

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mTextureView = view.findViewById(R.id.texture);
    mButtonVideo = view.findViewById(R.id.video);

    mButtonVideo.setOnClickListener(this);

    Spinner spin = view.findViewById(R.id.dropdownmenu);
    CustomAdapter customAdapter=new     CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),sights);
    spin.setAdapter(customAdapter);
}

CustomAdapter.java

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private int[] sights;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, int[] sights) {
        this.context = applicationContext;
        this.sights = sights;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sights.length;
    } 

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera2_video,(ViewGroup) null);
        }
        ImageView icon = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        icon.setImageResource(sights[i]);

        return view;
}

Layout.xml

<RelativeLayout
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dropdownmenu"
        android:layout_width="51dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/video"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/video"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="-15dp"/>
```

I need to display two images on the drop-down menu that, when clicked, change an imageView somewhere else on the screen.  The drop-down menu is displaying other buttons that don't have a function inside the drop-down menu, however they do have other separate functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need init Array.

```
int[] sights=new int[]{1,2,3};
```

Comment: Just replace this in the line right under the "//Drop down menu"? I did that and nothing changed.